# partial differentiation of function of expectation of random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, partial-derivative

We have $E(U)=\int_0^B V f(V) dV + B \int_B^\infty f(V)dV$; Here $V$ is random variable. $E(U)$ stands for expectation of $U$. We have $Z=f(E(U))$ i.e. $Z$ is function of $E(U)$. Can we write $\frac{\partial Z}{\partial B}= \frac{\partial Z}{\partial E(U)} \times \frac{\partial E(U)}{\partial B}$ ?

Comment: I suppose $U=V1_{V\leq B} + B1_{V > B}$. Also, E[U] is a function of B. If you fix B, then E[U] is a constant. Could you kindly clarify?

Comment: Yes the definition of $U$ is correct. $E(U)$ is a function of $B$.

Comment: Edited the problem too. there was a mistake. replaced $C$ by $B$ all throughout.

Comment: If $E(U)=\int_0^B V f(V) dV + B \int_B^\infty f(V)dV$ and $E(U)$ stands for expectation of $U$, I fail to see how $V$ is a random variable. In fact, so far the object $V$ does not even exist since for example $\int_0^B V f(V) dV=\int_0^B x f(x) dx=\int_0^B t f(t) dt=\ldots$ Please clarify.

Comment: Actually we have $U=min(V,B)$ where V is a random variable. I will give an example. Say you are selling an item. $V$ is random demand for the item. $B$ is quantity of item you have on hand. So $U$ is the quantity that you end up selling.

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(B)=\int\limits_0^B x f(x)\mathrm dx + B \int\limits_B^\infty f(x)\mathrm dx$ and $K(B)=h(g(B))$.

Then $K'(B)=g'(B)h'(g(B))$ where
$$
g'(B)=\int_B^\infty f(x)\mathrm dx.
$$

Comment: So $h'(g(B))$ means $\frac{\partial h(g(B))}{\partial g(B)}$ correct ?

Comment: Except that $h'(g(B))$ is rigorous and nonambiguous while the notation involving a partial derivative in your comment as the ones in your question can only cause confusion and mistakes.